# How to construct javascript date object from date and time string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date string like `08/27/2014` and time string like `18:29` . I want to convert it into javascript Date object.

Previously i was only concerned about the date so i was doing

```
var date = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', '08/27/2014');
```

But now i am concerned about the time also. How can i include time now.?

I did something like this now

```
var d_p = $('#dt').val().split('/');
    var t_p = $('#tt').val().split(':');
    var date = new Date(d_p[2], d_p[0], d_p[1], t_p[0], t_p[1], 0, 0);
```

But looks ugly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myDate = new Date('2014-08-27T18:29:00');
alert(myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Date constructor:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

How about this:

```
var date = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', '08/27/2014');
date.setHours(18).setMinutes(29);
```